# Mac cannot print - Windows Server 2019

Tags: mac, network-printer, printer, print-server

We created a new print server on a windows server 2019. Our Windows machines can connect and print to the printers without issues. On our Mac computers we can map the printers but as soon as we try to print something it will not go through. Printers will show that it is trying to print then will ask for the users AD credentials after putting in the information the printer won't print and will go to a PAUSE state right away.

I read that a certain update broke the smb printing on windows server 2016 way back in 2021. But that update and fix might have been integrated to server 2019 already.

We use PaperCut, SMB for mapping (Looking to use LDP but Org doesn't allow it) and I already included the "encryption=no" clause when mapping but didn't help.

These are non-AD Mac computers

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is in the event log on the server with the printer in the paused state?

Comment: It goes to pause on the MAC environment only, Printers are still on Ready state on the server side.

Comment: Is there any data or communication reaching the print server? This sounds like a dud product that does nothing. At a minimum you need a netmon packet capture on the print server and a correlated packet capture on the Mac

Comment: I believe there is communication going through as I can access the shared folders on that server and I can map the printers on the MAC side. This is currently happening on all of the printers on the print server. I already tried using MAC computers on the latest and Beta OS versions but still behaving the same thing.